# Flexbox columns overlap

Tags: flexbox

I am trying to mimic the WinJS grouped list view using flexbox. I am getting close (I think) except that the columns overlap when resizing.

http://jsfiddle.net/w8ts4Lnx/5/

I want the items to stay inside the group and let the group grow horizontally.

```
body {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
}

h1 {
   padding: 1em;
}

#content {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #eee;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

#content > .group {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
    background-color: #ddd;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap; 
    max-height: 600px;    
}

#content > .group .item {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    width: 200px;
}
```

Any ideas what I'm missing?

Answer (score 49):

If you don't want your content to overflow the container you must specify `flex-shrink: 0;`

> **flex-shrink** [source](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-flexbox-1/#valdef-flex-flex-shrink)
>
> This 'number' component sets flex-shrink longhand and specifies the flex shrink factor, which determines how much the flex item will shrink relative to the rest of the flex items in the flex container when negative free space is distributed. When omitted, it is set to 1. The flex shrink factor is multiplied by the flex basis when distributing negative space.

Im not sure what winJS behavior you're trying to mimic since i've never used winJS, however I think this is closer to the proper behavior you're looking to achieve: http://jsfiddle.net/w8ts4Lnx/11/

Answer (score 4):

The columns overlap because the contents doesn't fit. The Items don't fit in the group, so they flow-over. 
To solve this you have to specify an overflow-strategy for the group-div, with "**overflow**" like this (the last one):

```
#content > .group {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
    background-color: #ddd;

    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap; 
    max-height: 600px; 

    overflow: hidden;
}
```

The default is `visible` which make them fall outside. Read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

There are other options than `hidden`. You can set vertical/horizontal scroll, or both. Just choose whatever gets you closer to that desired "WinJS grouped list view". Try:

```
overflow-x: scroll;
overflow-y: auto;
```

or

```
overflow-y: auto;
overflow-x: scroll;
```

Happy coding!

Comment: but I don't want to overflow, I want for the group container to adjust based on the contents.

Comment: Then set "overflow" to "hidden". The group container will grow  when you make the window bigger and you will get no hints that there are more items if they don't fit.

Comment: Hi wojjas, were you able to find anything?

Comment: Sorry but I wasn't aware I was suppose to be looking for something :-) I am certain I answered on Oct 26. When you set it to "hidden" they will not overflow and the container will grow as much as its container (the window for instance) will allow it. Am I misunderstanding your question? then please clarify.

Comment: Oh I read at one point in your comment that you will try to look at it last Sunday. I tried overflow: hidden but that just hides the overflow contents, it does not adjust the container. If you can try it on the jsfiddle link I provided in my original question, that would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar issue and in my case the fix was removing the height setting on the container styling. This allowed the container size to grow with the changing browser heights.

Answer (score 1):

"let the group grow horizontally"- You have to use the flex-direction as "row" on the .group, and you have to wrap the groups inside the #content, then it won't overlap anymore..

http://jsfiddle.net/gafcvq9b/2/

```
#content {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #eee;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    flex-grow: 1;
}

#content > .group {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #cfcfcf;
    background-color: #ddd;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap; 
    max-height: 600px;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be best not to set width since you want flexbox to dynamically determine it. so I removed it and then I added flex grow to increase the first group.

http://jsfiddle.net/mspriyakk/vv3tfrtv/3/

```
#content > .group:nth-of-type(1) {
    flex-grow: 2;   
}
#content > .group .item {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #aaa;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct answer that's fixes overlapping columns:

```
.flex-container {
   display: flex;
   flex-flow: column;
}

.flex-item {
   flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be a little late, but I made a codepen, where I was working with this problem, maybe it will help to the people reading this question.

html

```
<body>
  <div class="test-container">
    <div class="item item1">
      item1
    </div>
    <div class="item item2">
      item2
    </div>
    <div class="item item3">
      item3
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

css (scss)

```
.test-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 100%;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
  padding-left: 2rem;

  .item {
    opacity: 0.6;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    flex-basis: 100px;
    margin-left: -2rem;
  }

  .item1 {
    background-color: cyan;
    z-index: 10;
  }

  .item2 {
    background-color: blue;
    color: red;
    z-index: 20;
  }

  .item3 {
    background-color: black;
    z-index: 30;
    color: white;
  }
}
```

https://codepen.io/Garma/pen/ZZmNWg?editors=1100

Cheers